# Що означає слово "файдулі"?

Tags: значення-слів

На сайті [Наше. Тексти пісень](https://nashe.com.ua/song/263) натрапила на пісню "Файдулі, фай". Ймовірно, це вигуки, але все ж цікавить, що означають ці слова, адже ні в Інтернеті, ні у словниках жодної інформації не знайшла.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [ЕСУМ](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom6.pdf)

Слова знаходяться, але від того не легшає.

> **[фай<sup>2</sup>]** (у виразі *фай би му*) «вигук, що виражає nрокляття, побажання хвороби, смерті Г, Нед; uyp, пек О», [*файі́*] «тс.» О;
>
> очевидно, запозичення з угорської мови; уг. fáj «боліти» етимологічно неясне, можливо, продов­жуючи ф.-уг. *роδʼз(-) «стружка; роз­колювати», споріднене з манс. pol’ «кусок, тріска; штука», комі pel’ny «розколювати», саам. bǫđđit «розколю­вати».
>
> ВеЗн 74; MNTESz І 828; MSzFUE І 1 76.
>
> ---
>
> **[фай<sup>3</sup>]** «вигук, що означає майорін­ня, мигтіння» Шейк, [*фа́йкати*] «розлітатися, розвіватися; махати крилами Шейк», [*файкота́ти*] «тс.» Шейк;
>
> білоруська [*файт*] (вигук на позначення уда­ру, хапання), польська fajt (вигук на позначення падіння, бігу), fajtnąć «кивнути, махнути, захитати, заколисати; впасти, перевернутись, злетіти; скочити»;
>
> очевидно, звуконаслідувальні утворен­ня.
>
> Sfawski І 217; SW І 712.
>
> ---
>
> **[фай<sup>4</sup>]** «гарно, добре» (у виразі *то є такий фай*) О;
>
> очевидно, зворотне утворенння від *фа́йно* «гарно, добре» Нед, О; зіставляється також з уг. faj «вид» (О 2 326).
>
> Пор. **фа́йний**, **фа́йт**.

Гадаю, тут наросток [-уля](https://r2u.org.ua/guides/synyavsky/slovotvir_narostky), отже ьдемо відти.

> **[файда<sup>1</sup>]** «циганський батіг з довгої палиці і шматка полотна Шейк; довгий
>   батіг Нед», [*фанда́*] «довгий батіг», [*фанди́сько* Шейк, *фанди́ще*] «тс.», [*фандо́ля*] «довгий батіг»;
>
> не зовсім ясне; можливо, пов'язане з [*хвойди́на*] «лозина», [*хво́їти*] «бити лозиною».
>
> Див. ще **хвойди́на**.
>
> ---
>
> **[файда<sup>2</sup>]** «люлька» Корз, [*файду́ля*] «тс.», [*файди́ти*] «курити люльку», [фай­дули́ти] «тс.» тж;
>
> неясне.
>
> ---
>
> **фа́йда<sup>3</sup>** — див. **хво́йда**.

---

Чомусь здається, особливо через *фай<sup>3</sup>*, що означає *гомону*, *шуму*, *звуку і руху міста* тощо.

Особливо при пошуку зустрічається [фай-дулі](//google.com.ua/search?q="%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%96"&lr=-lang_ru&safe=off). Тому  *дулі* може [бути](//zaxid.net/faydulifaydulifay_n1252631) як додатковий (негативний?) вигук.

Comment: а "дулі" тоді що може означати? Аби якось тоді між собою поєдніти ці частинки. Не натрапляли на таку частинку слова?

Comment: Можливо, якщо поєднати -уля ("істота жіночої статі з відтінком то іронічної пестливости, то згрубілости) + файт (у третьому значення), то утвориться приблизно так: файна + ж. р. (дівчина, жінка тощо)?

Comment: Доволі цікаво! Дякую!!!

Comment: Так, я зрозуміла, але і це добре, бо у мене навіть припущень жодних не було щодо цього слова.