# Що таке "чичері"?

Tags: значення-слів

Мабуть багато людей чули веселу пісню "Ой, Марічко, чичері". Зацікавилась значенням слова "*чичері*". На жаль, в українських словниках не знайшла нічого подібного. В російському словнику *чичер* — це пронизливий, холодний осінній вітер з дощем. Дане пояснення в контексті пісні зовсім недоречне. Чи можливо це слово вжито просто для зв'язки слів? Чи має воно якесь значення?

Comment: Я думаю, що це може бути вигуком на кшталт "файдулі", про що висував гіпотезу один із дописувачів цього сайту. (Питання: ["Що означає слово “файдулі”?](https://ukrainian.stackexchange.com/questions/3485/Що-означає-слово-файдулі))

Comment: http://forum.slovnyk.ua/index.php?showtopic=2299

Comment: Є навіть така думка: https://www.facebook.com/permalink.php?story_fbid=1514155588710482&id=811367038989344&comment_id=1514416348684406&comment_tracking=%7B%22tn%22%3A%22R%22%7D

Comment: Хоча, по-моєму, ані те, ані інше не має стосунку до дійсності — це радше справді вигук, що римується із «кучері» (як і каже Оксанка Струс).

Comment: Завжди було цікаво, чи пов'язане це слово з прізвищем Чичерін.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Мені, [як і Оксанці Струс](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/3560#comment6220_3560), це здається радше просто вигуком.

Серед слів у [«Етимологічному словнику української мови»](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm), що могли сприяти саме такій формі вигуку (але не задають на 100 % значення вигуку, бо це перш за все вигук, навіть якщо він звуконаслідує якісь інші слова):

- чечува́тися, чочува́тися — гратися в [чіт на лишку](http://sum.in.ua/s/chit);
- чече́кати, чиче́ка́ти — сюрчати, щебетати, цвірінькати;
- чі́ча — квітка або цяця (в дитячій мові).

Answer (score 8):

Є версія, що чічері якось пов'язане із закарпатським діалектним словом "чіча" і 
"чічка". 
У Словнику закарпатської говірки (Словник закарпатської говірки села Сокирниця 
Хустського району за ред. І Сабодаша - Ужгород, 2008. - С.416): 
"чіча" означає "що-небудь дуже гарне", "чічка" - "квітка", або "жінка, що дуже любить 
чепуритися, наряжатися. часто змінювати свої наряди". Тому, Марічко, мовляв, 
гарна чічко.

Ще у Словаччині біля Кошице є село [Чічер (Csicser)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C4%8Ci%C4%8Darovce), 93% населення якого 
складають угорці.

В історії іншого угорського села [Толчва](http://www.nemzetijelkepek.hu/onkormanyzat-tolcsva_en.shtml) також згадується дворянська родина 
Чічері (the Csicseri family), яка правила тут у 1414-1445 роки. І взагалі є угорське не мало поширене прізвище Чічері.

Тому, мабуть, Марічко Чи(и,і)чері (як прізвисько) або Марічко з села Ч(и,і)чері.

А ще в угорській мові csicser, csicseriborsó означає нут (Hungarian-English Dictionary by Franz de Paula Bizonfy - Budapest, 1886. - С.65). 
Ще є фонетично близьке слово [csicsereg](https://onlinefordito.micom.hu/szotar.php) - "щебетати, розмовляти", що співпадає зі значенням з попередньої відповіді пана @Sasha: чече́кати, чиче́ка́ти — сюрчати, щебетати, цвірінькати.

Тому семантику пісенного "чичері" варто шукати в Угорщині і угорській мові, бо тут збіг найбільший, хоч, можливо, і не виправданий.

Answer (score 1):

*Чичері* — це вітер, холодний або різкий або пронизливий.  Саме тому поруч з *чичері* згадуються *"розчеши мої кучері"*. Тобто, *"Маричка-вітер, розчеши мої кучері"*. Інші версії не відповідають логіці, бо ігнорують сам текст пісні.

> *Ой, Марічко, чичері, чичері, чичері,
>
> Розчеши ми кучері, кучері, кучері.
>
> Я би тобі чесала, чесала, чесала,
>
> Коби мамка не знала, не знала, не знала.*

> *Мати буде дивити, дивити, дивити,
>
> Як ся буду ганьбити, ганьбити, ганьбити.*

Comment: Вам би додати якесь підтвердження своїм словам. Може [тут](http://forum.slovnyk.ua/index.php?showtopic=2299) можна щось надибати.

Comment: Ласкаво просимо на сайт Ukrainian Language.SE! Будь ласка, почитайте про [наші критерії](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/5/), за якими ми оцінюємо хороші відповіді. Цей допис не відповідає таким критеріям: 3. Якщо маєте посилання на джерела чи на додаткові подробиці — наведіть їх. Ви завжди можете виправити відповідь, надавши більш аргументовану відповідь. Для цього натисніть [edit].

Comment: До того ж, на нашому сайті неприпустимі образливі вислови щодо дописів інших користувачів - лише обґрунтована нейтральна критика. Отже якщо у відповіді лишатимуться "пуста балаканина", "дуже шаблонно" й "тулити", а також не додасться жодне джерело до вашого пояснення - мені доведеться видалити відповідь.